# SQL - not sure how to join tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to join two tables like this:

Table A

```
ID    Value1
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

Table B

```
ID    Value2
1     A
3     B
4     C
```

Result should be:

```
ID    Value1  Value2
1     A       A
2     B       null
3     C       B
4     null    C
```

I.e. join Table A to Table B on ID.  If ID doesn't exist in Table A, add the ID from Table B.

The closest I've come is:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, a.Value1, b.Value2 
FROM 
    TableA a 
OUTER JOIN 
    TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

That gives me the new rows from TableB, but the ID is null.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the way to go.

Comment: Left join will not work to get his expected result.

Comment: LEFT JOIN doesn't add the final row, it just adds the Value2 column.  OUTER JOIN adds the Value2 column and the final row, but not the ID in that row.

Comment: ***What*** concrete RDBMS is this for? SQL is just the query language - but that doesn't cover all the vendor-specific extensions / interpretations of the SQL standard.... please add a relevant tag, like `oracle`, `sql-server`, `postgresql`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using....

Comment: @marc_s Sorry, it was Oracle.  Fixed the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close, you just need a little push in the right direction:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID, B.ID) As ID, a.Value1, b.Value2 
FROM TableA a 
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID=b.ID
```

The `COALESCE` function returns the first parameter it gets that is not null. since this is a full outer join, `a.id` will be null on one row and `b.id` would be null on a different row.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not available on all DBMS.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks for a quick reply.

Comment: @sagi outer join and full outer join are basically the same, though the last is more readable IMO. if the OP is using outer join he should be able to use full outer join as well. I am unaware of any database that supports `outer join` but not `full outer join`.

Comment: `MySQL` supports `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and not `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @sagi that wasn't my question. I asked about a database that supports `outer join` but not `full outer join`. a `left outer join` is not equivalent to `outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Just a note: you should not name your tables in SQL with spaces in them.

Comment: that would return 4 columns: id, id, value1, value2.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not available on all DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the basic for joining different tables

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

For your case:

```
SELECT a.value1, b.value2 
FROM TableA a 
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID=b.ID
```

remember full outer join

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the table (tableA) and from the table (tableB) and the FULL OUTER JOIN keyword combines the result of both LEFT and RIGHT joins.